# Would there ever be a reason to wrap a scalar UDF in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

My question is pretty much as simple as it sounds - I have a scalar function that takes a unique ID and returns a name. A team member recommended that "instead of calling the function directly" I "create a stored procedure that calls the function". I don't know of a viable reason for this (though my Google searching has lead me to believe that UDF's are widely despised for apparently not being as efficient as they sound), other than perhaps some sort of access or permission thing.

My SQL savvy is admittedly low, so would there be any reason to have a stored procedure that did literally nothing except make a singular call to a function?

Comment: No good reason I can think of, unless there's some critical detail you're leaving out.  It wouldn't be more efficient, and you wouldn't have the ability to call it inline in a query, which is the purpose of UDF's as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @Tab Nope, it's simply `SELECT @ReturnVar = Name FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.ID = @ID`

Comment: Do you ever use this to get Table1.Name for every row in a resultset, or do you only ever use it to get 1 name for 1 ID?

Comment: It's only ever for one ID. I did, however, change the function to a straight up stored procedure (_not_ a proc that calls the original function), because at 28k rows, the table was bigger than I thought, and the procedure version performed better.

Comment: Maybe that's what your colleague was trying to suggest, because with the scenario you describe, a proc would return faster than a function, but a proc calling a function would not.

Comment: Possibly, but my discussions with her didn't seem to convey that. At any rate, thanks for the help!